# How does a python package import a higher level module

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am trying to understand how a lower level package 'knows' about a higher level module such that calling it doesn't result in an error. My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── foo.py
├── script.py
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
```

My file contents are as follows:

`foo.py` contains:

```
class Foo():
    print("foo")
```

`pkg/__init__.py` contains:

```
from foo import Foo
```

`script.py` contains:

```
from pkg import Foo

foo = Foo()
```

From the directory where `script.py` is located, I can run `python script.py` and it results in "foo" being printed.

How is `pkg/__init__.py` able to successfully import `Foo` even though `foo.py` is located in a higher level directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: I searched through the information there, but I have not found any examples or explanations relating to a module importing something from a higher level directory yet.

Comment: are you running your script through some IDE like pycharm or through terminal? and another way is to check is `import sys print(f"The module search path is : {sys.path}")` , usually IDE adds project folder in the path.

Comment: I'm just running it through terminal, no IDE. Yeah, the first path in sys.path is indeed the top level directory where script.py is located.